# I cannot run google chrome without --no-sandbox argument

Tags: kali-linux, chrome, sandbox

I use this version of Kali Linux :

```
Linux kali 5.7.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.7.6-1kali2 (2020-07-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I downloaded google chrome from chrome's website and installed it with this command:

```shell
dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

When I launch google chrome by typing `google-chrome` in the terminal, that is what I get:

```
[1984:1984:0726/112742.739106:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(89)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supm/638180.
```

But when I launch it by typing `google-chrome --no-sandbox` it works correctly. Sometimes chrome notifies me that there is a lack of security because it works without sandbox.

What does that mean? And what should I do in order to run chrome without `--no-sandbox`?

Comment: You seem to be logged in as root (see error message). Running as root is contra indicated.  You seem to be running kali, doing this an not knowing the first part of the comment is contra indicated. Kali is not a general purpose operating system. You will be better off using a different disto such as Debian, Ubuntu, mint, …

Comment: I logged as a normal user, but the same error appeared after running google-chrome command. Although kali is a general purpose operating system, but it can run specific application such as google chrome and virtual box.

Comment: Did you mean: "Kali is a special purpose operating system, but it can run other applications such a google chrome and virtual box."? The use of the disjunction in the original is a little odd.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Yes that is what I meant

Comment: See "About Kali Linux" on [What is Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/what-is-kali-linux/), specifically "Kali Linux contains industry specific modifications as well as several hundred tools targeted towards various Information Security tasks, such as Penetration Testing, Security Research, Computer Forensics, Reverse Engineering, Vulnerability Management and Red Team Testing."  If you have no idea what that means, or you aren't performing various Information Seccurity Tasks, you SHOULD NOT BE USING KALI as @ctrl-alt-delor is trying to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run it without `--no-sandbox` flag?
Add a user jake as an example, by `adduser jake`. It will then ask you some simple questions about the user and **EVERYTHING SHOULD BE LOWERCASE**

Then you need to install sudo in the root user using `su -` or `sudo su -` and nano. Then go to the /etc/sudoers file using `nano /etc/sudoers` and add this:

```
(user)  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

And use the keybinds to send nano, save and exit.
Then use `su jake` and install the GUI **Graphical User Interface** like GNOME, XFCE4 etc.

Then use the command to install chromium or firefox. But it needs to be ***EVERYTHING IN SUDO***

Let's talk about the question:

> What does that mean, and what should I do in order to run chrome without --no-sandbox?

You need to run a command with `--no-sandbox` flag IN IT. Chromium based apps also require you to have this flag in.